# Laravel. Поиск текста в файлах PDF, XLS, WORD, PPT

Tags: laravel, pdf, search

Стоит задача сделать поиск на сайте по содержимому файлов (PDF, XLS, WORD, PPT) конкретный папки. Названия (и путь) этих файлов хранятся в БД. PDF-файлы из-за больших картинок могут весить и по 20+ Мб. Собственно вопрос: как сделать поиск по тексту внутри этих файлов?

Делаю впервые такое. Логично было бы наверно создать отдельную таблицу с полями:

```
- id
- parent_id   // id записи с файлом
- file_text   // текст файла
```

и с помощью сторонних php-плагинов вытаскивать текст с этих файлов и записывать в эту таблицу.
Засунуть этот функционал в "Очереди". Потом, когда на сайте делается поиск, то искать уже в этой таблице по полю file_text и выдавать на выходе parent_id.

Насколько это правильный подход? Есть ли может более простые решения данной задачи?

Comment: Под словом WORD разумеется файлы *.doc и *.docx возможно даже *.rtf

Comment: Используйте для извлечения текста что-то вроде [Recoll](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/), а затем, по необходимости, Elasticsearch или аналог для full-text search. Также можете посмотреть в их документации и определить библиотеки для извлечения текста только из нужных вам форматов.

Comment: Recoll не совсем то, что мне нужно. Recoll - вроде ПО для десктопов. А мне нужно, чтобы все происходило на уровне PHP, без вмешательства модераторов. Вытаскивать вручную тексты никто не будет. Файлы так же могут перезаписываться.

Comment: Изучайте дальше - Recoll это коллекция инструментов, которые могут использоваться откуда угодно (Web, Desktop etc), если его сконфигурировать на нужную вам папку то он будет делать большинство из того что вам необходимо. Смотрите возможности командной строки в [UNIX man pages](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/manpages/index.html).